# Python scrapy xpath return array

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am a newbie in scraping, i want to extract some data from this [link](https://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco) using xpath selector! but when I input this in chrome console

```
$x('//*[@class="deal-details"]/h2/text()')
```

it returns an array like

```
Array[1015]
```

from which i cant extract the value, how to get the value from array ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scrapy you can use scrapy's `shell` comand:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco"
>>> results = response.xpath('//*[@class="deal-details"]/h2/text()')
>>> len(results)
1015
# just the first one
>>> results.extract_first()
u'Ticket to "Don Pasquale" at San Francisco Opera'
# all 1015
>>> results.extract()
[u'Ticket to "Don Pasquale" at San Francisco Opera',
 u'The I Spa',
...]
```

Then you can do whatever you wish with those results.